# Regex: ignore whitespace between fields

Tags: c#, regex

I am faced with an interesting C# string splitting problem.  I have the below data that I require to be split into key / value pairs.  The problem is that the data itself does not delimit on space characters very well.

Sample Data:

```
Somefield1:500 Somefield2:atextfield Somefield3:a text field with spaces Somefield4:102 Somefield5whichisblank: somefeild6:m0redata somefeild7:(1,2,3     5)
```

The approach I am attempting to use matches the delimiting space character using a regex split:

```
var lineOfText = @"Somefield1:500 Somefield2:atextfield Somefield3:a text field with spaces Somefield4:102 Somefield5whichisblank: somefeild6:m0redata somefeild7:(1,2,3     5)"
foreach (string match in Regex.Split(lineOfText, @"\s(?=[^\)]*(?:\(|$))").Where(s => s != String.Empty))
      {
       // Split into key / value pairs here
      }
```

The issue is with my regex.  I think the solution is close, however its currently matching spaces in-between the fields.  [gskinner example here](http://regexr.com?35vku).

If someone could assist assist in fixing my regex in order to not match the 'inbetween' spaces, or offer an alternative method that would be super.

Thanks again.

Comment: Tip: To get the fields' names you should concentrate on getting `words` which are connected to the `:` character

Comment: Yes, this put me onto the correct track, thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this regex: `\s(?=\w+:)`